# Count all instances where certain word appears across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel document with several sheets and I would like to count the number of times where a certain word ("absent") appears in the same cell (B1) across all sheets (4 sheets).

I have written the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1:Sheet4!B1, "absent")
```

However that is not working. I'm getting `A value used in formula is of wrong data type` error. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D formulas work with certain functions only, and countif is not included.

You can find more details here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f

A workaround could be to have somewhere additional cells in the worksheet with code like `=if(b1="absent", 1,0)` than you can use SUM.

Comment: How would I use that to count for all sheets though? I'm an Excel noob.

Comment: Enter the formula from my answer to e.g. B2 in each sheet than prepare your 3D formula using SUM referring to B2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Máté Juhász](https://superuser.com/users/427317/m%C3%A1t%C3%A9-juh%C3%A1sz) for the valuable guidance, basically it can't be done with `COUNTIF` unfortunately but there is an alternative (though for difficult) way, so here's how I did it for anyone wondering:

1. Locate a cell that is blank on all sheets (example C1).
2. Select the Sheet1 tab, press and hold "**Shift**", and select the tab of the last sheet (4).
3. Select the blank cell identified in step 1 (C1).
4. Type `=if(B1 = "absent", 1, 0)`
5. On the sheet that you want the total to appear in (perhaps a new sheet after the last sheet), select a cell and type
   `=sum(Sheet1:Sheet4!C1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT, a List of the sheets and COUNTIFS:

Put you sheets in a range (like I1:I4)

Then

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&I1:I4&"'!B1"),"absent"))
```

The SUMPRODUCT will iterate the range with each sheet and sum each countifs.